# How to push to jquery array from php using ajax?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I run the following on the server (PHP), where I loop my posts and I grab some coordinates I have in a gmap field:

```
      $location = get_field('location');
      $lat = $location['lat'];
      $lng = $location['lng'];
```

I then create a single pair of lat and lng coordinate like this:

```
      $coordinates = $lat.", ".$lng;
      echo $coordinates;
```

And then on the client in JavaScript ajax success I push each of those pair in an array `var coords = [];` which I have in the footer.

But I get a weird result in console:

```
["4"]
(index):148 (2) ["4", "0"]
(index):148 (3) ["4", "0", "."]
(index):148 (4) ["4", "0", ".", "7"]
(index):148 (5) ["4", "0", ".", "7", "2"]
(index):148 (6) ["4", "0", ".", "7", "2", "7"]
(index):148 (7) ["4", "0", ".", "7", "2", "7", "2"]
(index):148 (8) ["4", "0", ".", "7", "2", "7", "2", "0"]...
```

So this is the whole code:

PHP

```
      function data_fetch(){
        $dates = $_POST['dates'];
        $dates = explode(',', $dates);
        $args = array(
          'meta_query' => array(
            array(
              'key' => 'anno',
              'value' => array($dates[0], $dates[1]),
              'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
              'type' => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
          )
        );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
        if( $query->have_posts() ): while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
          $location = get_field('location');
          $lat = $location['lat'];
          $lng = $location['lng'];
          $coordinates = $lat.", ".$lng;
          echo $coordinates;
        endwhile; endif;
        die();
      }
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#searchNations").on("click", function() {
    //clearOverlays();
    fetch(datesSearch);
  });
  fetch(datesSearch);

  function fetch(datesSearch) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '<?php echo admin_url('
      admin - ajax.php '); ?>',
      type: 'post',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        action: 'data_fetch',
        dates: datesSearch
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(data);
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
          coords.push(data[i]);
          console.log(coords);
        };
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Interesting, you need to `console.log(data)` on the first line of the success handler. You are not getting back what you think (`"number,numner"`).

Comment: @RandyCasburn If I do that I get `49.302473949.2832529`

Comment: @RandyCasburn also changed the concatenation to `$coordinates = $lat+", "+$lng;` as it's php instead of `$coordinates = $lat.", ".$lng;` as I had

Comment: @RandyCasburn gosh, yes it is php, I was correct to use the dots, changed it back now

Comment: @RandyCasburn basically now I am having: `40.7272074, 8.57526649999999840.7197406, 8.563512299999957` which is correct but wrongly written, they are 4 coordinates and two pairs, should be `40.7272074, 8.575266499999998, 40.7197406, 8.563512299999957` so it is not splitting a single pairs

Comment: @RandyCasburn I added `echo $coordinates.", ";` which makes it fine but I get one last comma in the array

Comment: In php you are outputting your coordinates as a string, but processing them in javascript as json. Either push them into an array and encode them in php or split on newline in js.

Comment: That's easy, just after the while loop do `trim($coordinates, ",");

Comment: @msg I knew there was something in regards of json, I tried so many different ways, even pushing to a php array or using $.each, but with no luck. Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: @RandyCasburn removed the loop bit as it was giving me worn results as per the question code, I simply do             `success: function(data) {
              console.log(data);
              coords.push(data);
              console.log(coords);
            }` but there must be something with json, any code help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you are outputting your coordinates as a string, but processing them in javascript as json. You have to push the coordinates into an array and encode them:

```
if( $query->have_posts() ): 
    $coordinates = [];
    while( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
        $location = get_field('location');
        $lat = $location['lat'];
        $lng = $location['lng'];
        $coordinates[] = $lat.", ".$lng;
    endwhile;
    echo json_encode($coordinates);
    die;
endif;
```

Comment: ok thanks a lot, it works but we also need to remove the `-1` in the `js data loop` from `for (var i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {` to `for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {`

Comment: It's an array with two string elements. Remove your `parseJSON` call, as you told `$.ajax` that it should expect a json response and doing the decoding for you